# Amazon MWS ListOrders Misiing orders with different Currency/ Timezone

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using ListOrders api to get the orders from Amazon store https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk

I have set timezone to Europe/London

But some orders are missing from listorders api and these orders are having different currency (Euro) and perhaps placed from different country (Spain).

All orders with currency Pound are listed by api. I also tried changing time zone to Europe/Madrid, but still these orders are not listed.
What can be the cause? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I could help you if you submit some code you use for order api. All though changing timezone won't make any difference. If there are more than 100 orders to get then you have to use ListOrdersByNextToken to get next 100 orders, and that might be why you are not getting other orders.

Comment: well, I am not getting more than 100 orders at single time. Also these orders are missing from mid of list of fetched orders. i.e. orders prior and after than these missed orders are being fetched in api.

I am using the code form "ListOrdersSample.php"
I am passing 
$request->setCreatedAfter($start_time);
 $request->setCreatedBefore($end_time);

Comment: well again I can't help you until you post some code with your question.

Comment: Here is the code I am using:
(I tried to include it in `` but resulting in plain text )

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); 
$start_time = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z' , strtotime('-49 hours'));
$end_time = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z' , strtotime('-62 minutes'));

 $request->setCreatedAfter($start_time);
 $request->setCreatedBefore($end_time);
 
 invokeListOrders($service, $request);
 
   function invokeListOrders(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service, $request)
  {
         $response = $service->ListOrders($request); 
   print_r($response);
 }`

Comment: i don't have an answer but something i'm in the process of learning - when i'm submitting an mws request for orders one of the criteria is for when the order was 'created' versus when it was 'modified'. i've noticed that with some orders they are considered 'created' but because they are still 'pending' they are not actually real orders yet that will get sent. so when i ran another request for 'modified' orders the ones that i was missing came in. so i think in this case those orders were 'modified', were not pending anymore, and were thus complete orders.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this method to my Amazon Orders API class and It returned me 100 orders and also gave me a NextToken to access next 100 or remaining orders. You only need to set CreatedAfter date and MarketPlaceID all other are not required fields.

```
public function getOrderList()
    {
        $this->config['ServiceURL'] = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
        $this->serviceURL = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";

        $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client($this->aws_access_key, $this->aws_secret_access_key, $this->application_name, $this->application_version, $this->config);

        $request = new \MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();
        $request->setSellerId($this->seller_id);
        $request->setMarketplaceId($this->marketplace_id);
        $request->setCreatedAfter(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('-49 hours')));
        //new DateTime('-7 Days', new DateTimeZone('UTC'))


        try
        {
            $response = $service->ListOrders($request);

            echo ("Service Response\n");
            echo ("=============================================================================\n");

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
            echo $dom->saveXML();
            echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
        }
        catch(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Exception $ex)
        {
            echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
            echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
            echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
            echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
            echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
            echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
            echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
        }
    }
```